# How do I set the value of a URL field in the SharePoint 2013 JSOM

Tags: javascript, api, url, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Anyone know how to set the description and url of a URL field in the SharePoint 2013 JSOM?
All the field settings examples I've seen use `spListItem.set_item(fieldName,fieldValue)` which works great for simple fields like text or numbers, but it's failing for me on the complex URL field type.
I've tried passing in my URL field name and a comma separated `fieldValue = "descriptionText,url"`

I've also tried `SP.ListItem.parseAndSetFieldValue(fieldname,fieldValue)`, passing in the URL field name and the comma separated `fieldValue = "descriptionText,url"`.

Am I missing something simple here?

Answer (score 5):

Use the SP.FieldUrlValue object:

```
function updateListItem() {     
  var currCtx = new SP.ClientContext();          
  var web = currCtx.get_web();          
  var lists = web.get_lists();     
  var myList = lists.getByTitle("List1");     
  myItem = myList.getItemById(3);   
  var urlValue = new  SP.FieldUrlValue();
  urlValue.set_url("http://www.example.com");
  urlValue.set_description("test link");
  myItem.set_item("TestURL", urlValue);     
  myItem.update();
```

currCtx.executeQueryAsync(onUpdateListSucceed, onFail); 
    }

Answer (score 0):

here is an example on how to create a new SP.ListItem using javascript in SharePoint 2013 (Hyperlink or Picture):

```
 function createListItem() {  
   var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl);  
   var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TestList');  
   var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();  
   this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

   var hyperLink = new SP.FieldUrlValue();  
   hyperLink.set_url("http://cnn.com");  
   hyperLink.set_description("CNN");  
   oListItem.set_item('PetkaHyperLink', hyperLink);

 oListItem.update();  
   clientContext.load(oListItem);  
   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(  
     Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),   
     Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)  
   );  
 }
```

I got if from [How to set any SP.Field Value with JSOM (Javascript) in Sharepoint 2013 to New SP.Listitem](http://pointofint.blogspot.nl/2014/03/how-to-set-any-spfield-value-with-jsom.html)

Comment: Where is the difference to the previous solution?